# Can you connect to an SQL database and use the data from that database to update a table in SQLite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3-ruby

I am new to Ruby-on-rails and need to be able to build a Rake file that will connect to a corporate data source and then use the data to update a table in SQLite3.

Is that possible?  Should I be using a rake file?

I would eventually want to use a timer to run an update on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible indeed (as long as you have the permissions to establish both connections). It does not look like a task for a ruby on rails project; a simple ruby script will do the job, and you can schedule it using cron or any other scheduler tool (depending on the platform you use).